# How to run Angular 2 client app and Node server app on the same host

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have built an app in Angular 2 to fetch data from a DB, and used node/express to fetch data from the server and serve it to the Angular client. Currently both of them are running in different local hosts. How do I combine them into a single project and run it on the same host?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose your express site is running on `localhost:3500` and all api call begins with `/api`

create proxy.conf.json with the content

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3500",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

then edit `package.json` and change `"start": "ng serve",` to `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

now run the project using command `npm start`.**Note:-** ng serve will not work

For more information find [documatation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) here

Comment: Thanks for this info. One thing though, how would I go about making this run in production, and build from ng build?

Comment: it depends upon the tech stack you are using for the backend.you can rander replace the index view with angular index html or you can also use nginx an proxy server that can redirect your api requests to the port you want.