# How to connect html template with node.js backend?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, web

I have no idea how we connect an html theme/template with node.js back-end ?

Comment: When you have no idea, what you can do is, just search on Google. Then no idea becomes hundreds of ideas.

Comment: are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782600/5621827

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ read this one you will have clear idea

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at something called PugJS (https://pugjs.org). It is a templating engine for NodeJS, formerly known as Jade. It uses a different markup to HTML, but it's rendered into minified HTML when requested. It works best in conjunction with Express (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express). It renders variables and info passed from your backend too. It supports if statements and for loops.

Answer (score 0):

i can't explain this in one short message. But... i can support you.
You tagged "angular" in your post, so... the easiest way is -> follow the steps in the "getting started" guides from a framework/tool.
Here is the quick guide from angular. https://angular.io/guide/quickstart
If you have after the guide any questions, your welcome.